# How to filter the results based on the time in Azure Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am using the below query to filter the items that are going to expire in < 90 days by subtracting its Expiry date with the current time.

`| where ExpiryDate_s = ((todatetime(ExpiryDate_s) - now()) < (90d))`

The query is not working as expected though it is printing the expired results as well.

**For Example:**

I have the below results in the ExpiryDate_s column

[image]

I need the output only the items which are going to expire in < 90 days. In this case

[image]

Am I missing something here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
datatable(expiry_date:datetime)
[
    datetime(2020-08-06),
    datetime(2020-08-20),
    datetime(2020-08-20),
    datetime(2020-09-28),
    datetime(2020-09-30),
    datetime(2020-09-30),
    datetime(2020-10-19),
    datetime(2020-10-26),
    datetime(2020-11-08),
    datetime(2020-11-23),
    datetime(2020-11-24),
    datetime(2020-11-25),
    datetime(2020-12-04),
    datetime(2020-12-27),
]
| where (expiry_date - now()) between(0d..90d)
```

-->

```
| expiry_date   |    |            |
|---------------|----|------------|
| 2020-10-19 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-10-26 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-11-08 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-11-23 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-11-24 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-11-25 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-12-04 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
| 2020-12-27 00 | 00 | 00.0000000 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this. Now, I am able to get only the items that are going to expire in < 90 days.

But, I need to include this as well `todatetime` 

`| where (todatetime(ExpiryDate_s) - now()) between(0d..90d)`

Without this, I am getting an error like below 

`Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between StringBuffer and DateTime`